# Call python function based on command line argument

Tags: python

I have a script with several functions:

```
def a():
   pass

def b():
   pass 

def c():
   pass
```

Which by design will be invoked depending on cmd line argument. I can create several if statements which will evaluate which function should run:

```
if args.function == "a":
    a()

elif args.function == "b":
    b()
elif args.function == "c":
    c()
```

But is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can do it as in the example https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html#example. They use args.accumulate and this calls the function that is written in accumulate (i.e. sum or max). I think it should also work if you pass "a", "b" or "c" in accumulate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a dictionary like so

```
d = {"a" : a,
     "b" : b}
```

and then dispatch

```
d[args.function]()
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for a library like [`click`](https://pypi.org/project/click/)?  It lets you easily add command-line subcommands with a decorator.

```
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
def a():
   print("I am a")

@cli.command()
def b():
   print("Je suis b")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Sample output:

```
bash$ ./ick.py --help
Usage: ick.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  a
  b

bash$ ./ick.py a
I am a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `eval`
`eval(function_name_passed_as_argument + "()")`

```
def a():
   pass

def b():
   pass 
eval(args.function + "()")
```

This doesn't require the use of `if-else` logic. Function name passed as argument will be executed directly.

Answer (score 0):

You make a dictionary as already pointed out, but how are you going to handle a bad input? I would create a default method and use the `dict.get` method:

```
def fallback():
    print('That command does not exist')
    # add any code you want to be run for
    # a bad input here...

functions = {
    'a': a,
    'b': b
}
```

Then call the function by retrieving it:

```
functions.get(args.function.lower(), fallback)()
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has several built-in functions that we can utilize for instance [Argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html), this method pretty common in python for command line programmable application.
The basics:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.parse_args()
```

By this method, you can have something like this:

```
$ python3 prog.py -v
verbosity turned on
$ python3 prog.py --help
usage: prog.py [-h] [-v]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose  increase output verbosity
```

Comment: You don't describe how it can help. I see output, but no idea what is under the hood when call '-v' option.